# Display pdf from byte array to c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, arrays, filestream

I have made a program that encrypts and decrypts pdf files. I want them to be locked for anyone but me and to open them via my program only. After I encrypt the pdf I have it in a byte array.
Is there anyway to display the decrypted byte array of the pdf file to the form without deploying the file to the drive?

Comment: So you want to avoid writing the byte[] of the pdf file to disk?  And you just want to show the byte[] (rendered as text such as a hex editor would show) on the winform?

Comment: Yes I don't want to write the decrypted pdf to the disk, because then it would all have been redundant. I want to present the decrypted bytes stored in my memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a WinForms PDF viewer component that can load a PDF from a byte array. With the PDF viewer from Gnostice PDFOne .NET, here is the code:

```
PDFViewer PDFViewer1;
byte[] baPDF; // load the decrypted PDF to this byte array
...
PDFViewer1.LoadDocument(baPDF);
```

http://www.gnostice.com/docs/pdfone_dot_net/Gnostice_PDFOne_Windows_PDFViewer_PDFViewer_LoadDocument@byte[].html

NOTE: I work for this Gnostice company. Any other PDF viewer component, if it can load from a byte array, will work.

There is no need to save the decrypted PDF to the disk.

Comment: Thanks alot! only one little thing, When I tried to use LoadDocument to the  decrypted pdf's byte array I get an exception. Then I tried to load the regular pdf's byte array(with File.ReadAllBytes, no manipulating) and still the PDFException.. you might know why?

Comment: In that case, you need to send the decrypted PDF to the support people of the library.

Comment: Is it an open source library?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got some function called `GetDecrypedBytes()` that has the signature:

```
public byte[] GetDecryptedBytes();
```

*How you encrypt/decrypt things is outside the scope of the question at hand and I assume you know how to do this.*

Then you could write a function such as:

```
public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] bytes)
{
  StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
  foreach (byte b in bytes)
    hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
  return hex.ToString();
}
```

And that would turn the bytes into text that could be displayed somewhere.

And then you could do something on your UI such as:

`myTextBox.Text = ByteArrayToString(GetDecryptedBytes());`

Obviously, one could tweak the `ByteArrayToString` function to change how the hexadecimal representation of the bytes is displayed.

Comment: Thanks but its not that, it's just shows the hexadecimal representation of the PDF file, not presenting it

Comment: You'll need to either send the PDF to a browser with the adobe add-on or use a third party control. Alternatively, you might be able to convert it to XPS format and have an element host display a WPF control that can show XPS data.  There is no built-in PDF viewer for WinFotms.